# JavaScript: inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypal-inheritance

I tried to make inheritance, but I didn't expect that `this.array` will act like static member. How can I make it 'protected/public':

```
function A() {
    this.array = [];
}

function B() {
    this.array.push(1);
}
B.prototype.constructor=B;
B.prototype = new A();
```

Firebug:

```
>>> b = new B();
A { array=[1]}
>>> b = new B();
A { array=[2]}
>>> b = new B()
A { array=[3]}
```

Comment: Your last two lines are backwards, by the way. Set `prototype.constructor` *after* you set `prototype`.

Comment: I realize this is just an example, but why don't you do `this.array = [1]` instead?

Comment: Original code looks like: 
function Controller(uri) {
    this._controllerURI = uri;
    this._controllers = [];
    this._views = [];
    this._events = [];
}. It's just a sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not "private/protected", but this will make a new Array for each `B`.

```
function A() {
    this.array = [];
}

function B() {
    A.apply(this); // apply the A constructor to the new object
    this.array.push(1);
}
// B.prototype.constructor=B; // pointless
B.prototype = new A();
```

Comment: I think you mean `A.call(this);`.

Comment: @user(\d)* Perfect. Thanks. @minitech: could be apply - it works. Where I can find docs/sample code for your $Query replacement?